# %s is available for purchase in increments of %s in Magento only qty

Tags: magento

The rule %s is available for purchase in increments of %s in qtyincrements.phtml in Magento shows the name of the product and the qty. If you delete the first %s so only keep is available for purchase in increments of %s, it shows the name at the %s sign. So you need both signs for the qty.

Is there a way to only call the qty. We want to get: this product is available for purchase in increments of ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a wrapper for [PHP’s sprintf function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). If you only want to show the increment qty, remove `$this->getProductName()` from the function arguments and reword the string with only one %s. An example would be: `$this->__('This product is available for purchase in increments of %s', $this->getProductQtyIncrements())`